# MySQL connection through jump server (Sequel Pro or Workbench)

Tags: mysql, ssh, mysql-workbench, socks, sequelpro

Background: A client's site is hosted externally. Only whitelisted IP addresses can ssh to their server. My company recently moved into a shared space with a dynamic IP. I want to access mysql through sequel pro preferably.

I've set up a jump server and had that IP whitelisted. I can use this to access the shell with a simple tunnel: `ssh -t user@jump.com ssh -i keylocation user@client.com`

I can use a SOCKS proxy with filezilla by opening it with something like: `ssh -D 8080 -C -N user@jump.com` Then set filezilla to connect by SOCKS 127.0.0.1:8080.

Is there any similar method that can be used to connect to MySQL through a client on my local computer (A) going through jump server (B) to access mysql on localhost on the client server (C)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the solution to this was port forwarding.

```
ssh -t user@jump.com ssh -i key user@client.com -L 33060:localhost:3306
```

Basically what's happening is from my local computer i'm forwarding port 33060 on the jump server to 3306 (mysql port) on the client server.

If that connection is left open I can connect sequel pro by ssh to the jumpserver and connect to the database on the client server through port 33060.

Comment: Keep in mind that new MySQL Server 8.0 use 33060 as default port for X Protocol – https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/x-protocol.html. (5.7 also use this port for X Protocol but only if use enable X protocol plugin `install plugin mysqlx soname 'mysqlx.so';`)